# When getting a team using v1.0 API, beta resources are also being returned

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I send a GET for a team at least one resource the resources is in beta. The resource `teamDiscoverySettings` shouldn't be returned when the request is made to v1.0 API

I sent a GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{{teamID}} and the server responds with:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams/$entity",
    "id": "...",
    "displayName": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "internalId": "...",
    "webUrl": "...",
    "isArchived": false,
    "discoverySettings": {
        "showInTeamsSearchAndSuggestions": false
    },
    "memberSettings": {
        "allowCreateUpdateChannels": true,
        "allowDeleteChannels": true,
        "allowAddRemoveApps": true,
```

Shouldn't the beta resources only be returned withing the beta version of the APIs?

Comment: What beta resources are you referring? Most often APIs move from /beta endpoint to v1.0 to be generally available to all users.
Is your concern that you are seeing more properties returned that you didn't expect? In that case, you should use $select query option to pick the properties that you need.

Comment: The concern is the app I'm developing retrieves the resources, and sends them back to the Team.  As this is a beta resource it should not be used.  I would like to keep API and resources at the production level.